# Creating database without filename?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible to create a database only by giving it the logical name without the filename -> which should result in creating the database in the default path with the database name.mdf?

```
CREATE DATABASE A
ON PRIMARY (
name = Z)
```

I found this from Microsoft documentation:

> If data file name is not specified, SQL Server uses database_name as both the logical_file_name and as the os_file_name. The default path is obtained from the registry. The default path can be changed by using the Server Properties (Database Settings Page) in Management Studio. Changing the default path requires restarting SQL Server.

How come that when I try the query above I get an error:

> File option FILENAME is required in this CREATE/ALTER DATABASE statement.

Unless I misunderstood what `data file name` refers to here.

Comment: Yes - have you tried? Just use `CREATE DATABASE MyDb;` and `Enter`,  and you should have a new database called `MyDb` on your SQL Server... the database files will be based on the database name, and the layout as defined in the `model` database

Comment: I want to give the logical name myself. I already know that not specifying anything should create the database on the default path.

Comment: As @DanGuzman explained in his answer, if you specify the *logical name*, then you **must also** specify the file name - no way of specifying just the logical name - either nothing at all, or then both

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a restriction of the SQL Server `CREATE DATABASE` syntax. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-sql-server-transact-sql), the `<filespec>` clause is optional. However, when specified (to include a non-default logical name), both NAME and FILENAME must be specified. The `<filespec>` clause syntax is:

```
{  
(  
    NAME = logical_file_name ,  
    FILENAME = { 'os_file_name' | 'filestream_path' }   
    [ , SIZE = size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] ]   
    [ , MAXSIZE = { max_size [ KB | MB | GB | TB ] | UNLIMITED } ]   
    [ , FILEGROWTH = growth_increment [ KB | MB | GB | TB | % ] ]  
)  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use

`CREATE DATABASE A`

it should work.